# nginx/uwsgi don't serve any request

Tags: django, nginx, https, uwsgi

I have nginx, uwsgi, django stack.  There use to be an https serving from the nginx but I'm trying to disable it.

this is my nginx configuration files:

nginx.conf:

```
events {
worker_connections 768;
# multi_accept on;
}

http {

proxy_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_buffers 4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;

##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

##
# nginx-naxsi config
##
# Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
##

#include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

##
# nginx-passenger config
##
# Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
##

#passenger_root /usr;
#passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

site-available/mysite.com:

```
upstream django {
server 127.0.0.1:44000;
}

server {
listen          80 default;
server_name     www.mysite.com mysite.com;


charset         utf-8;
access_log      /var/log/nginx/mysite_access.log;
error_log       /var/log/nginx/mysite_error.log;

location /static/ {
    root   /opt/myapp/myapp/;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}

location / {
  uwsgi_pass  django;
  include     uwsgi_params;
}
}
```

When I run it with uwsgi i get this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousOperation: Invalid HTTP_HOST header (you may need to set ALLOWED_HOSTS): www.mysite.com
[pid: 12865|app: 0|req: 1/2] 84.94.36.146 () {36 vars in 571 bytes} [Mon May 26 07:12:55 2014] GET /favicon.ico => generated 0 bytes in 457 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 0 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

I put 'www.mysite.com' on my ALLOWED_HOSTS section in settings.py and it didn't help.
these are the lines I added in settings.py:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
'.mysite.com', # Allow domain and subdomains
'.mysite.com.', # Also allow FQDN and subdomains
]
```

When I run it with runserver i get this error:

```
[26/May/2014 06:53:09] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('\x00;\x02\x00\x0c\x00QUERY_STRING\x00\x00\x0e\x00REQUEST_METHOD\x03\x00GET\x0c\x00CONTENT_TYPE\x00\x00\x0e\x00CONTENT_LENGTH\x00\x00\x0b\x00REQUEST_URI\x0c\x00/favicon.ico\t\x00PATH_INFO\x0c\x00/favicon.ico\r\x00DOCUMENT_ROOT\x0f\x00/etc/nginx/html\x0f\x00SERVER_PROTOCOL\x08\x00HTTP/1.1\x0b\x00REMOTE_ADDR\x0c\x0084.94.36.146\x0b\x00REMOTE_PORT\x05\x0051792\x0b\x00SERVER_PORT\x02\x0080\x0b\x00SERVER_NAME\x10\x00www.mysite.com\t\x00HTTP_HOST\x10\x00www.mysite.com\x0f\x00HTTP_CONNECTION')
[26/May/2014 06:53:09] ";
                         QUERY_STRINGREQUEST_METHODGET
                                                      CONTENT_TYPECONTENT_LENGTH
                                                                                REQUEST_URI
                                                                                           /favicon.ico PATH_INFO
DOCUMENT_ROOT/etc/nginx/htmlSERVER_PROTOCOHTTP/1.1                                                               /favicon.ico
                                                  REMOTE_ADDR
                                                             84.94.36.146
                                                                         REMOTE_PORT51792
                                                                                         SERVER_PORT80
                                                                                                      SERVER_NAMEwww.mysite.com HTTP_HOSTwww.mysite.comHTTP_CONNECTION" 400 -
```

I read that this error may be caused by HTTPS request, but it doesn't seem to me that I redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS anywhere, cause I deleted all those configurations.

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: it looks like you are passing request to the django runserver and not to uWSGI.

Comment: @roberto I don't think so, if the request didn't got to uWSGI it wouldn't show anything on the log. And also both uWSGI and runserver listening to 44000 port.

Comment: it is not uWSGI that is writing that logs. uWSGI has a pretty unique log-format. the ones you are seeing is from the django runserver. And no, you cannot have both bound on the same port. uWSGI must be used in place of the runserver

Comment: sure they don't listen to the same port at the same time, but each time i activate one of them, it listens to 44000 port, which also used by nginx. so if runserver gets the request from nginx, I can't think of a reason why uWSGI doesn't...

Comment: they are two different issue: the runserver one is generated because you are using (from nginx) the uwsgi protocol (while the runserver speaks HTTP). The second is that the HTTP_HOST value is not consistent with your django ALLOWED_HOSTS setup. As you have already set it, i suppose you are not writing the domain name in the browser bar, but you are instead using localhost, or the ip of the nginx instance. Eventually, you can force (just for testing) nginx to set HTTP_HOST to a specific value using uwsgi_param HTTP_HOST foobar;

Comment: @arnoncohen Roberto has already given you some good pointers. Now, regarding `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, please put into your question the code with which you set it. It is possible you did not do it right.

Comment: @Louis I just edited, added the ALLOWED_HOSTS lines on my django settings.

Comment: @roberto , Im writing the domain name in the browser bar, and I get '502 bad gateway'. I got your point about the request not getting to uWSGI, but I don't know how to fix that. Regarding to the HTTP_HOST not consistent, where can I see it? I know the 'HOST' HTTP header but not the 'HTTP_HOST' HTTP header... Is it related to HTTPS?

Its import to say-the site have been working great with ssl and a different domain. The changes I made are domain name change, and ssl disable.The problems started since I did those changes.

Comment: I have met the same problem. And I find the reason is the version of python. I change python from 2.6 to 2.7. It's Ok now :)

Answer (score 0):

It's working now.
The problem was that the ALLOWED_HOSTS was already defined in the local_settings.py with the old domains. I updated the domains and it worked.
All the nginx configurations are correct, so the files attached here are useful.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using

`uwsgi --socket :8001 --wsgi-file test.py`

instead of

`python manage.py runserser`